# Nexmo Inbound message tracking

Tags: curl, laravel-5, vonage

I have used below code to send the message using Nexmo. which is running successfully and I am getting unique messageId in response.

```
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(
                [
                    'api_key' => env("NEXMO_API_KEY"),
                    'api_secret' => env("NEXMO_API_SECRET"),
                    'to' => $data['to'],
                    'from' => $data['from'],
                    'text' => 'Hi I am sending the message',
                    'callback' => $data['callbackUrl']
                ]
            );
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode($response);
```

**Response:** "message_id": "0D000000890273B7".

After sending the SMS, my customer replied the SMS. and I am trying to track the messages and stored into DB.
I have set the webhooks callback URL on Nexmo setting. which is also running and dumped the response.

```
[msisdn] => 121#######
[message_id] => 0B000000CB352009
[to] => 1#########
[message_timestamp] => 2018-04-09 15:04:45
[keyword] => YES
[text] => Hello I am replying the message.
```

**Here** I noticed that messageId is coming different, so How can we track the replied message is related to this messageId "0D000000890273B7"? Please help me out. I cannot match with phone number because we are not using phone number as unique.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to perfectly correlate SMS 'replies' as there is no concept of reply within the SMS specification, when the user sends a reply on their handset they are in fact composing a new message to the senderID of the message they received but no data is shared betweeen messages, all you have in an SMS is TO, FROM, TEXT and a TIMESTAMP. Everything else is local to the handset operating systems

Comment: So how we distinguish the message is replied for particular customer as chatting system.

Comment: As I said there's no perfect way to recognise a reply in SMS, the usual way to do this is to use separate phone numbers for each conversation a customer is having.

Comment: Ok, Can we send the extra parameter while sending the sms and return back in callBack URL?

Comment: No that won’t work as there is no relationship between a sent message and the one the user sends back. He callback url is just used for the delivery receipt